# Garbled text at end of file. Is this related to DDPE?

Tags: encryption, windows-8.1, sublimetext3

**Preface:** About a month or so, we upgraded our work systems from a Windows 7 desktop to a Windows 8.1 Dell laptop. Laptop's file system is NTFS with [DDPE file encryption](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/ddpe-enterprise-edition/pd) and desktop's file system is NTFS, but no encryption. I tagged in Sublime Text 3 because that's where I have been poking around trying to come up with a solution. I am having issues honing into this specific problem, so I am asking a new question.

**Problem:** We're getting garbled text issues at the end of file with any extension. Randomly happens to some files on computer restarts. Randomly means it sometimes happens, sometimes doesn't. Happens on projects started on desktop and projects started on laptop. Doesn't matter if the project has been opened during the computer's uptime or not. Seems totally random.

**Example:** filezilla.xml

```xml
        </LastServer>
    </Settings>
</FileZillZY_ ?
```

**Example:** Richmond2015.sublime-workspace

```xml
    "side_bar_width": 514.0,
    "status_bar_visible": true,
    "template_settings":
    {?c??A
```

**Attempts to fix:**

- changing between unix and windows line endings
- "ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save": true
- saving with different file encodings, some were defaulting to Western, changed to UTF-8

Comment: Perhaps a defect disc causes these issues - did you check the HD?

Comment: Haven't checked outside of the Windows Disk Management that says "Healthy"

Comment: I don't know how valid it still is, but I trust in the old rule not to trust MS alone. If you're interested to double-check, I can recommend DiskC heckup: http://www.passmark.com/products/diskcheckup.htm

Also, this q is a bit out-of-scope here, you may get more help on http://superuser.com/

Comment: Seems like a good rule :D. I ran that checker, and things look good. And thanks for the heads up on superuser, just asked the question over there.